# How to specify specific instance of exception when using `assertRaises`?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a custom exception:

```
class AError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
```

and a function that raises this exception:

```
def raise_a(self):
    raise AError(1)
```

Using `unittest`, how do I test that `raise_a` raises `AError` with an `a == 1`? Using:

```
self.assertRaises(AError, raise_a)
```

will pass if any instance of `AError` (such as `AError(2)`) is raised, but I want it to fail for `a != 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `assertRaises` as a context manager gives you access to the caught exception:

```
with self.assertRaises(AError) as cm:
    raise_a()

self.assertEqual(cm.exception.a, 1)
```